# PHP Soap client request time measurement

Tags: php, soap-client

I want to get for each call I do with Soap client a `total time` for the request.

I've searched everywhere for such in-the-box solution like `curl_getinfo` but nothing.

Tried to log the `__getLastResponseHeaders()` and `__getLastRequestHeaders()` - no info there about that (and yes- I had enabled the trace).

Is there another solution but to use `microtime` for measuring the request time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well PHP works in sync way anyways. it wont continue untill it has completed a function.

Just add time mes in your code.

```
// Start of code
$now = microtime(true); // Gets microseconds

// Rest of code

// End of code
echo "Time Elapsed: ".(microtime(true) - $now)."s";
```

You can pretty much use this anywhere.
or you could do excact curl req via command line: `time curl http://www.example.com/`
It times the whole request, including network latency.

In a commend line of PHP file would be `time php dancebattle.php`

There is a general liberally ment for that aswell: https://github.com/fotuzlab/appgati ( it unix only tho, so it wont work on windows)

Anyways, the best and most easy to use is microtime php built in function. I would personally stick with that.